# Load data from sql server to redshift (incremental)

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am looking for ways/methods to load data into redshift from sql server mainly and also incremental load. I would like to know the steps/ tools/languages which can be used to implement this task. SSIS is not an option

I am reading too many things related to spark,pyspark,sqoop etc but do not have a clear understanding.

Any articles would also help.

i may have to join multiple tables in rdbms and move to dwh

Thanks,
Jo

Comment: You can use Pentaho Data Integration (PDI) to serve your purpose. I am experienced with this ETL tool and found very easy to Design different steps in it. Incremental data transfer also possible by comparing available values in source and destination database.

Comment: Thanks mkRabbani. I will take a look. i had a demo with matillion and that tool seems good as well - haven't tried though. any data ingestion  techniques we can use ? i am trying to avoid tools currently and have it as 2nd option.

Comment: Yes, any data integration techniques can be used for our purpose.

Comment: i am looking for process to implement.

Comment: @Jo1811, If you are avoiding tools and want to use AWS service, then I will suggest AWS DMS. If you have audit column in SQL Server Tables (like Created or updated timestamps) then you can also use AWS glue to fetch the incremental data.

Comment: Thanks Abraham- can you please let me know how AWS glue can be used ?